# How do I refactor 2 statements to 1 in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

Suppose, I have code like

```
long i = foo();
int j = goo(i);
```

How do I refactor this in IntelliJ IDEA IDE so that it gets converted to:

```
int j = goo(foo());
```

Essentially, it is compressing 2 statements to 1.

Comment: You want an automated approach?

Comment: No. just want to use day to day while writing code for my java project.

Comment: If it doesn't bother you *that* much, you can probably leave them there, as if they aren't inlined by the compiler it'll almost certainly be inlined by the JIT compiler. And if you can, you can mark the variable `final` (you can do that automatically in Eclipse at least) and the bytecode compiler will do the inlining.

Comment: I know the compiler might do the inlining but I just want cleaner/smaller code. Seems like this should be a simple refactoring for the IDE.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/inline.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the cursor on the `i` variable, click it to select it and press OSX <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> to `inline` the statement.

On Windows it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>